# SQL Server: How to declare function as variable inside computed column

Tags: sql-server, function, calculated-columns

I have a function `DiffMinuti' which I use inside a computed column. I'd like to declare it as variable, to call just one time and optimize code. Thanks for your help:

```
ALTER TABLE Ticket ADD MinutiAllaScadenza AS ( " +
CASE
WHEN StatoTicketID > 3 AND dbo.DiffMinuti(DataArrivo, DataObiettivo) <0 THEN 10000000 
ELSE dbo.DiffMinuti(DataArrivo, DataObiettivo) 
END)
```

Thank you!
Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly in the computed column expression: You'd have to wrap the expression in another function

Comment: THX @gbn...I see by above domanager's answer. Now I have doubt on the most efficient way to do it...

Comment: @Larry: I'd keep the computed column personally. And I'd just keep it the way it is too, not bother with an extra function. Using a triggers *and* a computed column as pre domager's answers is idiocy IMO

Comment: THX @gbn. At least IN MY case, it seems almost too much to create a new calculated field with the triggers... unless there are actual benefits of the performances... let's see what others think and decide ...thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new field to store the DiffMinuti result and have a INSERT and UPDATE trigger to keep the value up to date, then just reference the new field in the MinutiAllaScadenza computed field (instead of calling the function each time).

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Ticket ADD DiffMinuti INT NULL
GO
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Ticket_DiffMinuti ON Ticket
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(DataArrivo) OR UPDATE(DataObiettivo)
    BEGIN

        UPDATE
            b
        SET
            DiffMinuti = dbo.DiffMinuti(DataArrivo, DataObiettivo)
        FROM
            INSERTED a INNER JOIN
            Ticket b ON a.TicketID = b.TicketID;

    END;

END;
GO
ALTER TABLE Ticket ADD MinutiAllaScadenza AS CASE WHEN StatoTicketID > 3 AND DiffMinuti <0 THEN 10000000  ELSE DiffMinuti END
GO
```

Comment: @domanager: Thank you very much! 

I did not think it was so complicated...what do you think is the most efficient way to calculate `MinutiAllaScadenza` computed field? 

The one described by you, or the one currently used by me, with the double call to the function `Diffminuti`? 

Thank you very much, you are very thorough and professional!

Comment: @Larry It really depends on how the table is being used, if there are a lot of bulk insert/updates and very few reads from the table you're method would be better, but if the data is fairly static and is queried against heavily the not having to call the function for each row returned should be more efficient.

Comment: @domager: you now have RBAR processing for the remaining computed column on top of 2ndary writes to the table for DiffMinuti in the worse case...